# how do we iterate and store the results in a variable in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a string say example "https://www.google.com" and a count of paging say 5
how do i iterate the URL to append p/page=incrementing numbers of paging and store the result in a variable as list?

```
"https://www.google.com/page=1"
"https://www.google.com/page=2"
"https://www.google.com/page=3"
"https://www.google.com/page=4"
"https://www.google.com/page=5"
```

So the end result will look like this having a variable query_var which will hold a list of string example below

```
query_var:("https://www.google.com/page=1";"https://www.google.com/page=2";"https://www.google.com/page=3";"https://www.google.com/page=4";"https://www.google.com/page=5");
count query_var  \\5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the join function `,` with the each-right adverb `/:`

```
query_var: "https://www.google.com/page=" ,/: string 1_til 6
```

Make it a function to support a varied count of pages:

```
f:{"https://www.google.com/page=" ,/: string 1_til x+1}

q)10=count f[10]
1b
```

Comment: Thank you so much James for your quick response, that's exactly I was looking for.

Comment: and say now we have symbol list of `syms:``aapl``msft``nftx` and we have a string ``"www.google.com/sym/info/history"``. How can i get a list of string which will iterate syms to the sting and give final output as ``desiredoutput:("www.google.com/aapl/info/history";"www.google.com/msft/info/history";"www.google.com/ntfx/info/history");
count desiredoutput  //3``

Comment: `{"www.google.com/",string[x],"/info/history"} each \`aapl\`msft\`nftx`

Comment: Or if you want to be adverb-happy: `"www.google.com/",/: string[\`aapl\`msft\`nftx],\:"/info/history"`

Comment: awesome, thank you very much again! Will learn more about adverb \:

Answer (score 3):

**Q1**

You don’t even need a lambda to make this a function. It’s a sequence of unary functions, so you can compose them.

```
q)f: "https://www.google.com/page=",/: string ::
q)f 1+til 6
"https://www.google.com/page=1"
"https://www.google.com/page=2"
"https://www.google.com/page=3"
"https://www.google.com/page=4"
"https://www.google.com/page=5"
"https://www.google.com/page=6"
```

**Q2**

```
q)("https://www.google.com";;"info/history")
enlist["https://www.google.com";;"info/history"]

q)"/"sv'("https://www.google.com";;"info/history")@/: string `aapl`msft`nftx
"https://www.google.com/aapl/info/history"
"https://www.google.com/msft/info/history"
"https://www.google.com/nftx/info/history"
```

List notation is syntactic sugar for `enlist`. The list with a missing item is a projection of `enlist` and can be iterated.

Again, a sequence of unaries is all composable without a lambda:

```
q)g: "/"sv'("https://www.google.com";;"info/history")@/: string ::
q)g `aapl`msft`nftx
"https://www.google.com/aapl/info/history"
"https://www.google.com/msft/info/history"
"https://www.google.com/nftx/info/history"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can assume a unique character that doesn't appear elsewhere in your url (e.g. `#`) then `ssr` is a simple and easily-readable approach:

```
ssr["https://www.google.com/page=#";"#";]each string 1+til 5
ssr["https://www.google.com/#/info/history";"#";]each string`aapl`msft`nftx
```